# Android work manager CursorWindowAllocationException of size Could not allocate CursorWindow 4194304 due to error -13

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-room, android-workmanager

If anyone experienced a similar issue. Would be appreciated for a solution

Component used:
Version used: android.arch.work:work-runtime:architectureWork:1.0.1

There is the error log:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException:
  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeCreate (CursorWindow.java)
  at android.database.CursorWindow.<init> (CursorWindow.java:145)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:319)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:159)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount (SQLiteCursor.java:152)
  at androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl.getAllUnfinishedWork (WorkSpecDao_Impl.java:1203)
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.resolve (WorkerWrapper.java:427)
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.resetPeriodicAndResolve (WorkerWrapper.java:561)
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.handleResult (WorkerWrapper.java:447)
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.onWorkFinished (WorkerWrapper.java:335)
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run (WorkerWrapper.java:310)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)


android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/user/0/com.testapp/databases/androidx.work.workdb' of size 4194304 due to error -13.
android.database.CursorWindow.nativeCreate(:-2)
android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:145)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:319)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:159)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:152)
android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:232)
android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:271)
be.b(SourceFile:16) (be = androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl)
androidx.work.impl.q.k(SourceFile:2)
androidx.work.impl.q.h(SourceFile:54)
androidx.work.impl.q.run(SourceFile:3)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: It is 2021, you should not be using ` android.arch.work` or the Support Library at all anymore. You're literally multiple years out of date at this point and not getting any bug fixes. You need to switch to AndroidX.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that it cannot get the 4M (4194304 bytes) CursorWindow. I suspect not because there isn't sufficient memory, but that it cannot allocate the file perhaps because the are insufficient file handles left.

I would look at your code and ensure that you are closing Cursors (using the Cursor `close` method) when you are done with them and especially look in loops.